# Variables with ssh and awk with perl

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk

Trying to execute remotely a bunch of commands in a perl script

This looks like that :

```
    $CMD1 = "/usr/sbin/mminfo -av -q \"savetime>'-1 day 18:00:00',savetime<'17:59:59'\" -r \"ssid,totalsize,nfiles,pool\"|grep \"xxxxx\"|/usr/bin/awk '!seen[\$1]++'";
    print Dumper $CMD1;
    $CMD = "/usr/bin/ssh xxxx\@$SRV \'$CMD1\' 2>&1";
    print Dumper $CMD;
```

But I still have problem with the $1 in the awk command, It seems to be cancelled when running.

What I can see :

```
$VAR1 = '/usr/sbin/mminfo -av -q "savetime>\'-1 day 18:00:00\',savetime<\'17:59:59\'" -r "ssid,totalsize,nfiles,pool"|grep "xxxxxx"|/usr/bin/awk \'!seen[$1]++\'';
$VAR1 = '/usr/bin/ssh xxxxx@\'xxxxxx\' \'/usr/sbin/mminfo -av -q "savetime>\'-1 day 18:00:00\',savetime<\'17:59:59\'" -r "ssid,totalsize,nfiles,pool"|grep "xxxxx"|/usr/bin/awk \'!seen[$1]++\'\' 2>&1';
```

So the '$1' of the awk command is passed correctly to the remote but when running :

```
    @RESU = `$CMD`;
    print Dumper @RESU;
```

I can see that my $1 is missing (or interpretated by the remote shell as a null value) :

```
$VAR1 = 'awk: ligne de commande:1: !seen[]++
';
$VAR2 = 'awk: ligne de commande:1:       ^ syntax error
';
$VAR3 = 'awk: ligne de commande:1: error: expression indice non valide
';
```

I've tried many things like quoting or double-quoting the string, creating the string with perl 'qq' function, putting value of $CMD1 directly in $CMD and escaping quotes but no way.

And of course, my awk is piped to another awk (not provided here).

I don't want a solution which runs awk localy since I've millions lines returned from the 'mminfo' command.

Any clue (or a better way to do that !) ?

Comment: I would recommend the module [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#Net::OpenSSH-methods) for executing remote commands. Then you should also be able to reduce the amount of quoting needed

Comment: The immediate problem is that the dollar sign in the Awk script will get interpolated by the remote shell. Adding a single backslash is not enough because the remote shell will do its own level of interpolation.  But really, running trivial shell commands in a pipeline is pointless; Perl itself can do this quite well. Minimize the amount of code you run in an external process to reduce the complexity as well as probably improve performance.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland : I cannot install CPAN modules...

Comment: @Denis.A Try use [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) it allows you to install modules without root priveleges.

Comment: @tripleee : my big problem is the amount of data returned by the mminfo command, I don't want to transfer millions of line to the perl process by the network. That why I run all the commands remotely, the result is a single line with only 2 fields...

Comment: @Håkon Hægland : It is not a privilege problem, It's a security rule : no external things... no access to external repositories...

Comment: $VAR1, $VAR2, $VAR3 are all values printed from the 'print Dumper @RESU;' which is the result of running the $CMD command containing the $CMD1 arguments. My code is only 6 lines long...

Answer (score 2):

You might want to break it into smaller pieces for readability, and use the multi-arg invocation of `system` to avoid perl having to spawn a shell. The `q()` function goes a long way toward avoiding quoting hell.

```
$mminfo = q{/usr/sbin/mminfo -av -q "savetime>'-1 day 18:00:00',savetime<'17:59:59'" -r "ssid,totalsize,nfiles,pool"};
$awk = q{/usr/bin/awk '/xxxxx/ && !seen[$1]++');
print Dumper [$mminfo, $awk];

@cmd = ( "/usr/bin/ssh", "xxxx\@$SRV", "$mminfo | $awk" );
print Dumper \@cmd;

system @cmd;
```

Comment: Thank you for factoring the grep out of that.

Comment: Problem with the @cmd line, I have to join the ssh and the credential in a single value (otherwise I got : String found where operator expected at ./charge-base1.pl line 501, near ""/usr/bin/ssh" "user\@$SRV "") and putting a comma between the connection string and the command to be passed. So it works,but how can I get the result of my commands since system does not returns any results ? (that what's I used the backticks)... Tried the qx function with no result.

Comment: Missing commas. Edited

Comment: You'll want to use the [IPC::Open3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Open3) module.

Comment: @Denis.A Consider [IPC::ReadpipeX](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::ReadpipeX) or any of the modules listed in its SEE ALSO section.

Comment: Sorry, but as I previously said, I cannot use external modules. But fortunately IPC::Open3 is available and IPC::Run, too...

Answer (score 1):

Even if you can not use modules in your final environment, you may be able to use them in your local machine. In that case you can use them to quote the command programmatically and then just copy and paste the quoted string into the script you are developing. For instance:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $quoted_cmd1 = Net::OpenSSH->shell_quote('/usr/sbin/mminfo', '-av',
                       -q => q(savetime>'-1 day 18:00:00',savetime<'17:59:59'),
                       -r => 'ssid,totalsize,nfiles,pool',
                       \\'|',
                       'grep', 'xxxxx',
                       \\'|',
                       '/usr/bin/awk', '!seen[$1]++');

my $SRV = "foo";
my $quoted_cmd = Net::OpenSSH->shell_quote('/usr/bin/ssh', "xxxx\@$SRV",    
                                           $quoted_cmd1,
                                           \\'2>&1');
print "$quoted_cmd\n";
```

Which outputs...

```sh
/usr/bin/ssh xxxx@foo '/usr/sbin/mminfo -av -q '\''savetime>'\''\'"''"'-1 day 18:00:00'\''\'"''"',savetime<'\''\'\''17:59:59\'\'' -r ssid,totalsize,nfiles,pool | grep xxxxx | /usr/bin/awk '\''!seen[$1]++'\' 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing scripts in Perl via ssh using the awk pipeline, then your awk variable must be escaped \\\$1 (three backslashes $1)